# How to restrict access specific ssm document can run only in specific ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-ssm

I am having the requirement of creating the policy that will have access to the custom created ssm document only can run in the specified EC2 instance.

I have tried policy something like this but it is not sufficient to control the document to be run on the instance.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:SendReply",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:document/xxxxxxxxxx",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Is this doable ?**

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968885/aws-iam-ssm-restrict-documents-that-instances-can-run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS IAM SSM - Restrict Documents that Instances can run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968885/aws-iam-ssm-restrict-documents-that-instances-can-run)

Comment: Where are you putting that policy?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein in my EC2 instance IAM Role.

Comment: @BrandonMiller thanks for your help. If I am correct, that post is to restrict User having access to document. But in my case I need to restrict on EC2 to receive from that Specific Document.

Comment: I have contacted AWS support they confirmed that it is not doable for now... Thanks